# How to get button id at .on "click" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Short question from a jQuery newbie:

Say I'm receiving an arry of json objects and my script generates a table row (the last td contains a button) in an existing table for each one of them. The index will be the id of the  and the class is "delete".

This works so far:

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(){
    alert('you clicked me!');
});
```

But I need the id of that button the send the delete request for the right object. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `this.id` because `this` inside the event handler refers to the target dom element.

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(){
    alert('you clicked me!' + this.id);
});
```

Comment: That was fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(e){
    alert('you clicked me!' + e.target.id);
});
```

Comment: it may not be always correct.. like it was `<a class="delete" id="el1">delete <img src="delete.gif" /></a>` and then if you click the image `e.target` will refer the `img` element where are `this` will refer the anchor element

Answer (score 1):

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JRkL4/)

`this` keyword will help you.

```
$(document).on('click', ".delete", function(){
    alert('you clicked '+ this.id);
});
```